# Best method for going from Photoshop to InDesign with masked text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, workflow, mask

I do almost all of my design initially in Photoshop, its just my personal preference and allows me personally the most creativity. But I do then take the proper steps to bring the finished design into InDesign if it will be Printed, as most of my work will be.

If I use a Layer Mask on text to create depth within a Photo what is the best method (workflow) to bring it into InDesign? Here's a quick example with everyone's favorite font.

[image: Its just Comic Sans MS, relax.]

Some possible solutions:

- I can just save this as high res as possible and not worry that the type is pixel then.
- I could crop out the part of the shoe that goes ON TOP, save that as transparent, and piece it back into place in InDesign.
- I could bring the photo alone into InDesign, type the text and then use Pen/Pencil tool in InDesign to go around the shoe. Then outline the text and use the ID Pathfinder to subtract it.

Is there another way? Which will provide the best final results?

Comment: Your question is *much* better phrased than the duplicate, unfortunately the duplicate has existing answers.

Comment: Ya, I edited the tags, maybe I'll edit a little bit of the question to so its easier to find. Not that I searched very long. @Scott

Comment: I would go with the fastest method and just place the whole image to indesign as it is. Otherwise it would just be generating extra work. Of course I'm saying this without complete knowledge of what you are doing. If each page in indesign would end up being just a raster image and nothing else, then maybe not :)